# ffmpeg latest visual studio builds or linking with (.a) libs

Tags: visual-studio-2008, gcc, ffmpeg, static-linking, solution

there is a problem.
I need to link ffmpeg(particularly libavcodec) statically into visual studio 2008 project.

I  found  some visual studio solutions in internet but they are very old (around 0.6 version) and i need latest version, so this way is not an option for me.

Next, I made static build (with --enable-satic --disable-shared flags) using MinGW/msys and obtained (*.a) libraries in output.
 In Visual Studio I go to the linker properities and add to Additional Dependencies(Linker->Input) libvacodec.a and libgcc.a.
Then i wrote simple application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern "C"
{
   #ifdef  __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
      #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
   #endif
      #include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"    
 }



#include "libavformat/avformat.h"

      int main()
   {
    av_register_all();
    return 0;
   }
```

Compilation of this code was succeeded but linking failed. There is an error was obtained:

```
error  LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl av_register(void)" (?av_register_all@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main.
```

So, there are two questions:

1. How to  link  Visual Studio application with libavcodec.a ?
2. If it possible, where can i get visual studio solution which includes ffmpeg latest version?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Just like you use a .lib file. .a is the same thing with different name. If it's easier for you, rename libavcodec.a to libavcodec.lib.
2. Nowhere.